# Set UserImage and Username in nav header from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm following this Tutorial to create blog and I successfully Created the blog. In give Tutorial, he has used Empty Activity but I used Navigation drawer Activity. 
So now I would like to put the User image and User name in nav header if he is signed in if not use the default image and name  from drawable folder.

My Blog Recycle Adapter is

```html
package com.nepalpolice.cdp;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import static com.android.volley.VolleyLog.TAG;
import static com.nepalpolice.cdp.webfaq.isNetworkStatusAvialable;

public class BlogRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<BlogPost> blog_list;
    public Context context;

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private PopupWindow popWindow;

    public BlogRecyclerAdapter(List<BlogPost> blog_list){

        this.blog_list = blog_list;


    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_list_item, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        final String blogPostId = blog_list.get(position).BlogPostId;
        final String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        String desc_data = blog_list.get(position).getDesc();
        holder.setDescText(desc_data);

        String image_url = blog_list.get(position).getImage_url();
        String thumbUri = blog_list.get(position).getImage_thumb();
        holder.setBlogImage(image_url, thumbUri);

        String user_id = blog_list.get(position).getUser_id();
        //User Data will be retrieved here...



        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    String userName = task.getResult().getString("name");
                    String userImage = task.getResult().getString("image");

                    holder.setUserData(userName, userImage);


                } else {

                    //Firebase Exception

                }

            }
        });

        try {
            long millisecond = blog_list.get(position).getTimestamp().getTime();
            String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(millisecond)).toString();
            holder.setTime(dateString);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        //Get Likes Count
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").addSnapshotListener(((Main2Activity) context),new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

               if (e!=null) {
                   Log.w(TAG, "listening failed",e);
                   return;
               }

                if(!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                    int count = documentSnapshots.size();

                    holder.updateLikesCount(count);

                } else {

                    holder.updateLikesCount(0);

                }

            }
        });

        if (InternetStatus.getInstance(holder.blogLikeBtn.getContext()).isOnline()) {
            //Get Likes
            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).addSnapshotListener(((Main2Activity) context), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "listening failed", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_accent));
                        } else {
                            holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_accent));
                        }
                    } else {

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_gray));
                        } else {
                            holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_gray));
                        }
                    }

                }
            });


        //Likes Feature



        holder.blogLikeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                        if(!task.getResult().exists()){

                            Map<String, Object> likesMap = new HashMap<>();
                            likesMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).set(likesMap);

                        } else {

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).delete();

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        }

    else{

        Toast.makeText(context, "Check Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


            holder.blogCommentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent commentIntent = new Intent(context, CommentsActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(commentIntent);

                }
            });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blog_list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mView;

        private TextView descView;
        private ImageView blogImageView;
        private TextView blogDate;

        private TextView blogUserName;
        private CircleImageView blogUserImage;

        private ImageView blogLikeBtn;
        private TextView blogLikeCount;

        private ImageView blogCommentBtn;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            blogLikeBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_btn);
            blogCommentBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_comment_icon);

        }

        public void setDescText(String descText){

            descView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_desc);
            descView.setText(descText);

        }

        public void setBlogImage(String downloadUri, String thumbUri){

            blogImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_image);

            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder);

            if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
                Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(downloadUri).thumbnail(
                        Glide.with(context).load(thumbUri)
                ).into(blogImageView);
            }
        }

        public void setTime(String date) {

            blogDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_date);
            blogDate.setText(date);

        }

        public void setUserData(String name, String image) {

            blogUserImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_image);
            blogUserName = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_name);

            blogUserName.setText(name);

            RequestOptions placeholderOption = new RequestOptions();
            placeholderOption.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_placeholder);

            if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
                Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderOption).load(image).into(blogUserImage);

            }
        }
        public void updateLikesCount(int count){

            blogLikeCount = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_count);
            blogLikeCount.setText(count + " Likes");

        }

    }

}
```

and my Mainactivity is

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {
    final Context context = this;
    private boolean exit = false;
    Dialog dialog;
    private Menu mymenu;



    private TextView blogUserName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        Fragment fragment = new main();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

//Create Dialog


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        mymenu = menu;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateService.class);
                startService(intent);
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.iv_refresh, null);
                Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_refresh);
                rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                iv.startAnimation(rotation);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    item.setActionView(iv);
                }
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) {
                    new UpdateTask(this).execute();
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void resetUpdating()
    {
        // Get our refresh item from the menu
        MenuItem m = mymenu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            if(m.getActionView()!=null)
            {
                // Remove the animation.
                m.getActionView().clearAnimation();
                m.setActionView(null);
            }
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.store) {
            String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Sagar%20Rawal&hl=en";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);


        } else if (id == R.id.contact) {
            Intent activity_about = new Intent(this, profile.class);
            startActivity(activity_about);


        } else if (id == R.id.weather) {
            Intent activity_weather = new Intent(this, com.nepalpolice.cdp.weather.MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(activity_weather);
        }

        else if (id == R.id.resistor) {
            Intent activity_weather = new Intent(this, com.nepalpolice.cdp.resistor.MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(activity_weather);
        }



        else if (id == R.id.result) {
            result fragment = new result();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, "Main");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        }

        else if (id == R.id.pacman) {
            Intent activity_about = new Intent(this, pacman.class);
            startActivity(activity_about);

        }

        else if (id == R.id.tetris) {
            Intent activity_about = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(activity_about);

        }

        else if (id == R.id.retro) {
            Intent intent500 = new Intent(this, com.nepalpolice.cdp.brickgame.GameActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent500);

        }

        else if (id == R.id.hangman) {
            Intent activity_about = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
            startActivity(activity_about);

        }


        else if (id == R.id.tictac) {
            Intent activity_about = new Intent(this, MainMenuScreen.class);
            startActivity(activity_about);

        }


        else if (id == R.id.home) {
            main fragment = new main();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, "Main");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);


        }
         else if (id == R.id.email) {
            Intent activity_about = new Intent(this, Sendemail.class);
            startActivity(activity_about);
        } else if (id == R.id.call) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+9779868336847"));
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.share) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Hey check out this awesome app at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nepalpolice.cdp");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.rate) {
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.nepalpolice.mnemonics&hl=en" + getPackageName())));
            }
            catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        (Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faraksoch.sagar.eroutine&hl=en"))));
            }
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (exit)
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Really Exit?")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            // MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                            finish();
                            moveTaskToBack(true);
                        }
                    }).create().show();

        else {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStack();


            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() ==1) {
                finish();
            }

            exit = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }, 800);

        }


    }


}
```

I have no clue if it is possible or not but if it is please help. I have followed several post but none of it helped.

My Firebase Structure is

[image]

Comment: is the user image path saved in your firebase database? if so could you show us the database structure?

Comment: Sorry, but there is *way* too much code here. Please look into [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to maximize the chances that someone can help.

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque, Ok I have updated my code and added Firebase Structure.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please look at my Firebase Structure in image, Hope it'll helps.